# Unable to create a new project with Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, service

I'm trying to create a Windows service using .NET.

I've tried Googling and the only thing I've found is a [page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/additional-components) saying you need to install 'additional components', but it doesn't say what.

I have been following [this](https://dzone.com/articles/create-windows-services-in-c) guide, and I am unable to get past step 1. I looked at another guide ([the official Microsoft one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer)) and it has the same thing.

I am on Windows 10.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: That [page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/additional-components) you found is for **Visual Studio Code**, while the [guide](https://dzone.com/articles/create-windows-services-in-c) you are following uses **Visual Studio**. They are (annoyingly) similarly named, but completely different IDEs. I don't use Visual Studio, but it may help those who follow that tag to clearly describe what errors you're getting, what's blocking you from getting past step1, and the VS version you're using.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying!
Should I get Visual Studio for this instead?
If not, then could you point me to a guide that uses VS Code?
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't use .NET and I don't know how to use VS Code for .NET. If the guide you are following is for Visual Studio, then get Visual Studio.

Comment: @RuthlessJailer you can use VSCode for .Net, but you have to configure it accordingly, start off with setting it up to [work with C#](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp) and then [.Net](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/dotnet)

Comment: @GinoMempin, could you post your first comment as a question so that I can mark this as solved? Thanks for the replies.

Comment: @RuthlessJailer Do you mean to post it as an *answer*? (You said *question*). Though I'm not sure what I should be answering..., because I'm not sure if you are going for Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code, and as I mentioned I don't use .NET. The best I can do is point you to a link to the VS Code tutorials on .NET, but [another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62825034/unable-to-create-a-new-project-with-visual-studio#comment111102006_62825034) already did that.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant.
The issue has been resolved and I'm not sure how to close the question other than deleting it.